# How to categorize classifiers and matrix factorization methods?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, recommender-system

I have a classification problem which is solved by a variety of methods. Among the methods are unsupervised methods, traditional classifiers and a supervised matrix factorization methods. The problem is that I'm trying to find a categorization for the methods. The problem comes when I try to differentiate between the traditional classifiers and the matrix factorization methods.

So far I made this categorization:

1- Unsupervised methods.

2- Supervised methods.

3- Matrix factorization methods.

However the problem is that the matrix factorization methods are also supervised so they also fall into that bin. But in principal they have somehow a different motivation or so, that's why I really want to put them in a different category but I'm not able to find a correct term for them. I also thought about putting them in a Recommender Systems category, but traditional classifiers also fall into that bin. So what do you suggest?

Answer (score 5):

Your taxonomy is peculiar. For starters, classification *is* supervised learning. When you don't know the classes, the problem is called *clustering*. Finally, matrix factorization is just a mathematical framework; you can apply it to either. The supervised case is obvious; the rows and columns can correspond to the input and output (or vice versa), respectively, whereas for the unsupervised case you can consider correlation matrices.

Are you writing a survey paper on recommender systems, by any chance?

Comment: yes I'm writing my thesis and I'm using matrix factorization method and a classifier to solve a task. Thus I want to put these in two categories.

Comment: For recommendation I would categorize by the type of ratings: implicit vs. explicit, rather than the mathemematical framework.